# Get post attachment images dimension and use in embed code

Tags: attachments, embed, images

I am trying to make things work like where any post attachment image will generate embed code automatically.

Example: If I upload and add two images 1. 250x150 2. 600 x 160 and insert into post. Now that image information I want to auto put into embed code like below.

```
<div>
<a href="link url" title="title text" target="_blank"><img src="$image_url" width="$image_width" height="$image_height" alt="$image_name" /></a>
</div>
```

where $variable is the data of the attached image/s.

So above code our team member can use the embed code to display image.

Comment: You'll need to write a plugin. Is that something you're looking to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has a predefined function, `wp_get_attachment_image_src` that returns the following information as an array:

```
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
```

But, the function requires that you know the attachment's ID, not the post's ID. In order to get that, you'll need to use `get_post_thumbnail_id`.

Here's the two functions together in action:

```
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id);
```

After that, you can easily do what you're talking about in your question.

```
<img src="$image[0]" width="$image[1]" height="$image[2]" />
```

If you want more information about the wp_get_attachment_image_src, you can read more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src.

Comment: Cool this is working completely fine but only one issue. I want to get size from post attachments it could be one or more and not from the thumbnail. Can you please help to do that. Also how to get image alt="" dynamically same like height width and src

Comment: Its done I used `$attachments = get_posts($args);` to get all attachments and used foreach and it works great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm really happy that I could set you on the right path.

Comment: Quickly related question. Now I want to get size of the attached image/s I mean in kb/mb. I want to display image kb on post. How can I get that?

Comment: There's a PHP function called `filesize()` than can return the size of a file in bytes, but it _looks_ like you have to supply a *PATH* and not a *URL*. I'll keep looking into it, but this seems a little trickier. You might want to open another question.

Comment: Cool I got it now one more help needed may be last for this topic. I want to display file type too. Like JPG, GIF PNG etc. Can you please help me for that too?